# How to recover PostgreSQL 13.5 database without backup file in Ubuntu 20.04 server?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I had 10-15 microservices databases running in production on Ubuntu server. 
 Accidentally deleted everything in the `/var/lib/postgresql/**` folder with command `sudo rm -r *`. I think PGDATA is inside the `/var/lib/postgresql/13/` folder. 
I tried [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to restore this folder but it showed everything deleted except the `13/` folder.
I only have backup files from a long time ago. 
Is there any way to restore the last data?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Not understanding *'... except the 13/ folder.'*. Does that mean you can see it?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I didn't see /var/lib/postgresql/13/ folder

Comment: That is just repeating the information in the question. Does the `/var/lib/postgresql/13/`  directory exist and can you descend into it? In other words can you do: `sudo ls -al /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/`?

Comment: this folder has deleted. I need to recover this folder

Comment: Are you saying `TestDisk` cannot see the deleted folder?